# why can't I install dbt-snowflake using miniconda?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, miniconda

I am trying to install dbt-snowflake 1.5.0 in my miniconda environment but it does not find the package...

```
conda install dbt-snowflake==1.5.0
```

but I get *PackagesNotFoundError*

Yet, if I try with pip, it finds and installs it

```
pip install dbt-snowflake==1.5.0
```

But in this case, it looks like dbt is not installed within my environment

Any idea how I could install this package within my conda environment?

Comment: Because that package is in the Pypi repo and not in the Conda repo?

Comment: Not entirely sure about the details but I found it in conda-forge and managed to install using


conda install -c conda-forge dbt-snowflake==1.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [NickW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13658399/nickw)

My package was in the "condo-forge" repository and I managed to install it using

```
conda install -c conda-forge dbt-snowflake==1.5.0
```